# How to convert a string to a signed float?

Tags: c++

like :

```
string num = "-0.25";
```

how can I convert it to a signed float?

Answer (score 2):

C++11: `std::stof(num)` to convert to `float`; also `stod` for `double` and `stold` for `long double`.

Historically: `std::strtod` (or `std::atof` if you don't need to check for errors); or string streams.

Answer (score 1):

[`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) is a good bet for C.

I have no idea if C++ has other bets.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `istringstream`:

```
std::string num = "-0.25";

std::istringstream iss ( num);

float f_val = 0;

iss >> f_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `atof` function.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

For C++ you can also use `std::stof`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/

Comment: `atof()` isn't really idiomatic *C++*, and even in *C* isn't usually recommended because it lacks any facility for error-handling.

Comment: @Emmet - the question was 'how to convert' and my answer will do the trick.  Boo on you for downvote.

Comment: The downvote was when your answer just mentioned `atof()`. What should we do when someone makes a recommendation that might work, but is the worst available option?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a signed float by using the function atof. Like :

`float myValue = (float)atof("0.75");`

Note that you should also checked if the passed value is a valid numerical value otherwise the behaviour could be unpredictable.

There is also an [other solution](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) :

```
    string mystr ("1204");
    int myint;
    stringstream(mystr) >> myint;
```